# Keystone file via form using s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3, keystonejs, keystone

File upload is not working via form in keystone when i try to upload it to Amazon s3 bucket
I am using keystone 0.4.0 beta version with jade.

This is my model

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;
var Email = require('keystone-email');

  var storage = new keystone.Storage({
  adapter: require('keystone-storage-adapter-s3'),
  s3: {
    key: process.env.S3_KEY, 
    secret: process.env.S3_SECRET, 
    bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET, 
    region: process.env.S3_REGION,
    path: '/cv',
    headers: {
      'x-amz-acl': 'public-read', // add default headers; see below for details
    },
  },
  schema: {
    bucket: true, // optional; store the bucket the file was uploaded to in your db
    etag: true, // optional; store the etag for the resource
    path: true, // optional; store the path of the file in your db
    url: true, // optional; generate & store a public URL
  },
});

  var Intern = new keystone.List('Intern',{
        nocreate: true,
        noedit: true,
 });

 Intern.add({
        name :{type: Types.Name , required:true},
        email: { type: Types.Email, required: true },
        phone: { type: String },
        qualification: {type:Types.Select, options:'Graduate, Post Graduate, UnderGraduate, Pursuing Graduation, Diploma, Others', default: 'Pursuing Graduation'},
        proficiency: {type:String},
        reason: {type: Types.Textarea, required: true},
        project: {type:String},
        createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        file: { type: Types.File, storage: storage },
 });
```

---

My jade code...

```
.col-sm-12
  form(method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data')
    input(type='hidden', name='action', value='intern')
    .col-sm-6
        .form-group
            label Upload CV
            input(type='file', id='cvId',  name='cvName').form-control      
            .form-actions
             button(type='submit').btn.btn-primary Send
```

---

and the js code

how should i use updatehandler to move my files to amazon bucket...??

Comment: Can you also provide the code from your route, since it's this part which will be handling the file upload.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you reference it from your route/js code, but as far as I can see, you call the file "cvName" in your jade form, but in your model, you call it "file". If you don't explicitly rename it or assign it in your route file, it doesn't know that is the file you want to save in the model's "file" field.